Pyspark job piling up memory
I have below scenario coded in a pyspark job:
df = read from file in s3. Not very big.
Some joins on df
[x,y,z] = df.collect to array   (Not very big array)
for i in range(10):
These rows from array I am batching in groups and sending to threads for further processing parallelly.
Inside thread I do below operations.
Use x, y, z values as well as some other dataframes which are globally stored in python file. e.g. return df2.filter(col[some_col] between x and y).collect
The problem I am seeing is after first loop ends i=1, the memory is getting piled up in the cluster and eventually after 2-3 more loops, the job is failing. Is there any way we can stop the memory leak?

after the df.collect all your data is on the driver node.
are you starting another spark process after that to distribute the data on the cluster ?
Where is the memory "piling up"  being observed ? on the driver ? other nodes ?
what processes are running on cluster ?
how exactly are you launching your "threads" ?

The memory is piling up in the overall cluster. After collect, new sparkcontext is not started but I am using the dfs created in parent process inside thread using global variables. I am using threadpoolexecutor to start the threads.
